# Django-phone-login Error

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm using [django-phono-login](https://github.com/wejhink/django-phone-login) on my project. But after all the settings I have such an error when migrating:

> : (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'phone_number', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'PhoneTokenAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'phone_login.PhoneToken'.

Then I downloaded the folder phone-login and putavil within the project and commented out the line that gives the error:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import PhoneToken


class PhoneTokenAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # list_display = ('phone_number', 'otp', 'timestamp', 'attempts', 'used')
    search_fields = ('phone_number',)
    list_filter = ('timestamp', 'attempts', 'used')
    readonly_fields = ('phone_number', 'otp', 'timestamp', 'attempts')

admin.site.register(PhoneToken, PhoneTokenAdmin)
```

And then all is well no error, but it (phono_login / generate /) message does not send to the number. If anyone helps please.sorry for my English!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tm35.png)

Comment: can you add `PhoneToken` model ?

Comment: where ? It be me phono_login.models.PhonoToken.

Answer (score 2):

Just update the `django-phonenumber-field` package to the newest Version. Django-phone-login specificied `django-phonenumber-field==1.1.0` in the requirements but the newest version is 2.1.0. After the update it should work.